# Getting Android Contacts From Local Contacts Only

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have an app that allows the user to enter a phone number or select one from their contacts. To do this I use :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
//intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT); //PICK_CONTACT is defined earlier as 1
```

This works fine, but it includes contacts from various apps such as Facebook emails and such. If I uncomment

```
//intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
```

It only shows contacts that you would see in the Contacts app, but it doesn't return phone numbers. Any way to fix that?

I do have the READ_CONTACTS permission.

Code to read the Uri of the contact

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    if(reqCode != PICK_CONTACT) return;

    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(data.getData(), null,
            null, null, null);

    if (cur.getCount() <= 0) return;
    while (cur.moveToNext()) 
    {
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
        {
            // Query phone here. Covered next
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null); 
            while (phones.moveToNext()) 
                //phone is the EditText view where the user enters a phone number
                phone.setText(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));

            phones.close(); 
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but it doesn't return phone numbers

If you add the `READ_CONTACTS` permission, you can query `ContactsContract`, either to present the entire list yourself, or to query to get the phone number of a contact the user selected via `ACTION_PICK`.

Without `READ_CONTACTS`, you have no right to access contact phone numbers by any means, other than the user typing one into your app directly.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I do have the READ_CONTACTS permission. It still returns phone numbers of the contacts, should I uncomment the line of code.

Comment: @ADiabeticBadger: In your question, your problem is that `ACTION_PICK` is not returning a phone number. In your comment, your problem is that it *is* returning a phone number. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, having issues typing. I meant that when I uncomment the line of code, it shows just the contacts you would see in the contacts app, but it won't return a phone number even with the READ_CONTACTS permission.

Comment: @ADiabeticBadger: That's what I expected, but I haven't tried using `setType()` on `ACTION_PICK` this way, and so I wasn't completely sure. `ACTION_PICK` is supposed to return a `Uri` of the contact. Use a `ContentResolver` or `CursorLoader` to query `ContactsContract` to get details of the selected `Uri`, including the phone number.

Comment: I've updated the topic to show my code to read the Uri. What do I need to change so it reads the phone number?

Comment: @ADiabeticBadger: Off the cuff, what you have seems fine, if perhaps a bit awkward, and doing I/O on the main application thread (which is bad). If you are not getting your phone number, set some breakpoints and/or add some `Log` statements to figure out where things are going awry in your `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: After adding a few log statements, with the line uncommented, the cursor `cur` has one row, but it will not enter the while loop, even moving the cursor to the first row.

Comment: @ADiabeticBadger: The simplest thing is to just get rid of that first `query()`. as you should be able to get your ID by calling `ContentUris.parseId()`, passing in the `Uri` you get from `data.getData()`. This also saves one round trip to the `ContentProvider`, saving a bit of time.